# Having html and variable in switch statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

What would be the correct way to accomplish this ?

```
var parameter = json.Parameter;
switch (foo)
  { 
      case "0" : foo = "There is no link";
        break;
      case "1" : foo = "Here is a link : <a href=\"www.alink.com/?" + parameter + "\">Link B</a>";
        break;
  }
$("#result").append( foo);
```

The way I tried this b would just look print "Here is a link : " but not the actual link.

Comment: Can you tell us what "links" stands for? And what do try to accomplish?

Comment: It is just an arbitrary variable name... a foo. In the actual scripts I am working with it is an integer that is returned in an xml.. I changed my question so hopefully it is less confusing.

Comment: I don't like to edit people's code to tidy it up... but you might want to slap a few line indents in there ;-)

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/HjP2G/ (I did add the http protocol to the url though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try altering `'` and `"`

```
foo = "Here is a link : <a href='http://www.alink.com/?" + parameter + "'>Link B</a>"
```

Comment: You get the answer .. because you were the closest.. I just screwed up the quotes in my real code.

Comment: any way you have to add the `http` protocol part

Answer (score 3):

You can invoke the pretty unknown method `.link()` like:

```
links = "Here is a link: " + "Link B".link("http://www.google.com");

$("#result").append( links );
```

That is cross-browser since Netscape navigator days. However, I guess your actuall problem was that you didn't quote the value of the `href` attribute. But, you can just use `.link()` to be fine here.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/SNHeW/

Comment: ahh.. sadly the problem was in my real code, a forgotten quote! Doh.. so I should go to sleep.. but.. almost.. done...

Comment: @Sushi K: That is why you should show the actual code that you are using. It's hard to find a problem in the code you are using by looking at some other code that you are not using...

Answer (score 0):

When I try it, it adds the link just fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/RsMKP/

You need a `http://` in the URL for it to work, though.

Javascript:

```
var foo = '1';
var parameter = 'asdf';
switch (foo) {
  case "0" :
    foo = "There is no link";
    break;
  case "1" :
    foo = "Here is a link : <a href=\"http://www.alink.com/?" + parameter + "\">Link B</a>";
    break;
}
$("#result").append(foo);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```